# Is it possible to create Html content from json data in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dom, html-to-pdf, html-rendering

I am trying to create an html content from json data in react native. Basically i want to generate PDF from html content which i have already done using static html content in my react native app, but now we want to generate pdf with dynamic content and decide the data to be in json and convert them into html content and then generate pdf from the html content.

Our web team has already done this rendering the json data into dom and then generating pdf from the dom using react.

Is it possible to achieve the same using react native.

Comment: can you write your JSON data? so i can see the format fo JSON data

Comment: if you make the pdf on serverside, you will need to process the json and react (js) on the server before inputting it into the pdf maker. hence you will need something like nextjs or similar to give the pdf maker a pre-compiled html input

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this like doing this- **(use backticks instead of single or dubble quotes)**

```
const JsonData = {
   title: 'My PDF File',
   image: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/pdf.png'
}

const html = `
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>MyPDF</title>
     <style>${htmlStyles}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>${JsonData.title}</h1>
    <img src=`${JsonData.image}` />
    {JsonData.otherData}
  </body>
</html>
`;
```

Checkout example for this:
https://github.com/vishalpwr/react-native/tree/master/CreatePdf